# Laravel 5.6 route 404 Error on SignUp

Tags: php, laravel

Can't seem to figure out the problem with this Route. return 404 error. I have checked the route list table and his route is inside. since I get 404 I assume that there is a routing error, maybe a typo but I have not been able to see anything. i updated this post to show my blade files...

```
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name   | Action                                         | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+--------+------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |        | Closure                                        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |        | Closure                                        | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | signup   | signup | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@postSignUp | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+--------+------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

UserController:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request['email'];
        $username = $request['username'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->username = $username;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses'=> 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);
```

welcome.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Welcome!
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class ="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <form action="{{route('signup')}}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">UserName:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>


@endsection
```

master.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Welcome!
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class ="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <form action="{{route('signup')}}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">UserName:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: How are you accessing the route?

Comment: Show us your blade template code also - for the form request

Comment: just updated to show blade files

Comment: What does your final HTML look like? Also, does the web middleware expect some request parameters or something that causes a premature 404?

Comment: When you say final HTML what are you referring to?

Comment: maybe you have defined another route like /{param} that is overriding the /signup route, please add the exact error in dev mode too

Comment: Did you clear caches? `$ php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

you have forgot to set namespace in UserController class

Answer (score 0):

Would help to set the php artisan serve first then change all the htdoc directives to allow all

Answer (score -2):

you should run "php artisan make:auth"

Comment: This is not an answer for a problem. `make:auth` creates set of templates, controllers, and routes for sing up/sign in mechanism.